# Terminal won't allow me to enter command after "rails server" any answer please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-mavericks, railsapps

I am very new to this platform, after starting webrick my terminal not allowing me to enter command, is there any clue for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably if you started your webrick, your server is now running and listening on `http://localhost:3000`. To see it, simply open a browser and point to that address.

If you want to stop the server (and enter other commands) as you seem to want to do, press `ctrl + c` to kill the server

Comment: Hi Derek, what about without stopping server, I wan to use start writing codes for my new application, how can I do that, is there any command we have to use...

Comment: the best way to do that, is to just leave the terminal running on that tab, and open a new one to do your active development. You can do this by pressing `ctrl + t` or `apple + t` depending if you are on a mac or not

Comment: you can then also put the windows side to side so you can see what is going on in the server logs while you code

Comment: I got the answer, instead of writing "rails server" write "rails server -d" to run server as a Daemon

Comment: or you can do that to daemonize it - though why would you want to? Its actually quite useful to see the logs while in development since it can give you good clues to where your code is wrong. I would once again reccommend, to simply leave it running and open another tab to do development :)

Answer (score 1):

What happens is when you start a webrick server, that specific terminal get occupied.

There are two methods of then writing more commands.

- Either press `ctrl` + `t` and you will have a new terminal opened up where you can go to the same directory where you were and then write your commands there.
- Or, you can make the server run in the background using : `rails s&` and you can get it in the foreground using `fg`